# tel: link with span style not working?

Tags: html, href, styling

I'm trying to create a tel: link but with some styling however it's not working. I have this at the moment but it's not working

```
<font color="#ffffff"><h1><span class="InfinityNumber"><a href=“tel:08000306866”>08000306866</a></span></h1><font>
```

http://london.wrongfuel-angel.co.uk/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 1):

Use `""` instead of `“”`

```
<font color="#ffffff"><h1><span class="InfinityNumber"><a href="tel:08000306866">08000306866</a></span></h1></font>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/58n8ef1p/1/)

Comment: thanks but it's still not click to call on mobiles?

Comment: Make sure you properly close the `font` tag as `</font>`